# HTML button hit counting

Tags: javascript

I make an infinite game and I wanted to count the clickings. I tried everything but nothing worked. I'm starter at programming but I love it now. Please someone help me! This is the code (2 things: 1. Sorry for my bad English; 2. I tried to copy the best way the code but this doesn't show everthing):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type=text/css>
            .button {
                background-color: red;
                float: center;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                display: block;
                margin-top: 300px;
                margin-bottom: 0%;
            }

            .body {
                background-color: yellow;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body class="body" id="body">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="button" style="font-size:50px" ; id="gomb">Nyomj meg!</button>
        <script>
            var count = 0;
            var a = true;
            var gomb = document.getElementById("gomb");
            var body = document.getElementById("body");

            gomb.onclick = function() {
                if (a == true) {
                    gomb.style.background = "yellow";
                    gomb.innerHTML = "Na még egyszer!";
                    body.style.background = "red";
                    a = false;
                } else {
                    gomb.style.background = "red";
                    body.style.background = "yellow";
                    a = true;
                }
            };

            function myFunction() {
                if (count == 5) {
                    gomb.style.display = "none"
                } else {
                    count = count + 1;
                };
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem, the count is not being displayed? THe count isn't incrementing correctly? What is your desired outcome.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the code:

window.addEventListener: this help you to rearrange the code so that the event click and the variables are assigned when the page is loaded.

Use addEventListener to attach an event to html element

It's unusefull to give an id and name to body.

```js
var count = 0;
var a = true;
var gomb;
var body;

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  gomb = document.getElementById("gomb");
  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  gomb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (a==true){
      gomb.style.background = "yellow";
      gomb.innerHTML="Na még egyszer!";
      body.style.background = "red";
      a = false;
    }
    else
    {
      gomb.style.background = "red";
      body.style.background = "yellow";
      a = true;
    }
  });
});

function myFunction(){
  if(count==5) {
    gomb.style.display="none"
  }
  else
  {
    count=count+1;
  };
}
```

```css
.button{
  background-color:red;
  float: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
  margin-top:300px;
  margin-bottom:0%;
}
body{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="button" style="font-size:50px"; id="gomb">Nyomj meg!</button>
```